# Recursive triggers and error : subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, recursion, triggers, nested

I need your help !

I am working on sql server 
1-- I created this trigger but it seems to be wrong...

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[chargeAZero] 
ON [dbo].[situations_final] 
after INSERT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SET nocount ON 

      UPDATE sfinal 
      SET    charge = 00 
      FROM   inserted i 
             INNER JOIN situations_final sfinal 
                     ON i.referencepiece = sfinal.referencepiece 
                        AND i.ancienposte = sfinal.ancienposte 
                        AND i.numerophase = sfinal.numerophase 
                        AND i.datestrategie = sfinal.datestrategie 
      /*and i.Datecadence=sfinal.Datecadence*/ 
      WHERE  (SELECT sfinal.nouveauposte 
              FROM   situations_final sfinal 
                     INNER JOIN inserted i 
                             ON i.referencepiece = sfinal.referencepiece 
                                AND i.ancienposte = sfinal.ancienposte 
                                AND i.numerophase = sfinal.numerophase 
                                AND i.datestrategie = sfinal.datestrategie) IS 
             NULL 
  END
```

The error message is always the same: the subquery returned more than one value... I think I wrote my trigger correctly as I did with others that work fine.

2-- My second question is : Is it possible to make only one trigger recursive ?

3-- As you have noticed on my database on the table "Nomenclatures" (Bill of materials in english) I have 3 elements:
*codepiecemere: The component mother
*codepiecefille: the component child
* the quantity.
I give you an example of what I need : 
Mother= A    Child= B    Quantity= 2 
Mother= B    Child= C    Quantity= 3

I want a trigger to give me a result like that: 
A    1    B    2    C    6=2*3 (the quantity needed of C to make 1 B).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive query that solves the material aggregation problem.

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Material](
  [Mother] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [Child] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

and the query:

```
WITH Result(mother, child, quantity)
AS
(
    select * from material 
    union all
    select M.mother, R.Child,  M.quantity * R.Quantity as Quantity
    from Result R INNER JOIN Material M ON M.Child = R.Mother 
 )
 select * from result
```

You can see an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6dc64/1

**UPDATE:**

Sql fiddle is not working, I don't know why

**UPDATE 2**

Sql Fiddle is back! :-)

Comment: Here is the error I got :
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "QUANTITY" of recursive query "RESULT". –
I've found some help in this website using cast but it doesn't work because there is an operation (M.quantity * R.quantity).

Comment: I 'm not able to reproduce the error, maybe you can try to convert the two values to the same numeric type: select Mother, Child, CONVERT(Numeric(10,0), Quantity) as Quantity from material 
 union all
 select M.mother, R.Child,  CONVERT(Numeric(10,0), M.quantity * R.Quantity) as Quantity
 from Result R INNER JOIN Material M ON M.Child = R.Mother

Comment: I'm gonna try something. Can you put a picture in a comment showing the result you've obtained, please? ^^

Comment: Paolo Costa, thank you very much !! 
You are the best ! 
Thank you again

Comment: Hello !! 
Can you please take a look to my new answer ? 
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

The `is null` is not normally used with subqueries.  Try this:

```
        where  not exists (select 1
                           from SITUATIONS_Final sfinal inner join inserted i
                                on i.ReferencePiece=sfinal.ReferencePiece
                                   and i.AncienPoste=sfinal.AncienPoste
                                   and i.numerophase=sfinal.numerophase
                                   and i.datestrategie=sfinal.datestrategie
                          )
```

This is assuming that the `is null` is testing for no values being returned, as opposed to a `NULL` value in `sfinal.nouveauposte`.  If the latter:

```
        where exists (select 1
                      from SITUATIONS_Final sfinal inner join inserted i
                           on i.ReferencePiece=sfinal.ReferencePiece
                              and i.AncienPoste=sfinal.AncienPoste
                              and i.numerophase=sfinal.numerophase
                              and i.datestrategie=sfinal.datestrategie
                      where sfinal.nouveauposte is null
                     )
```

EDIT:

Do you need the subquery at all?

```
  UPDATE sfinal 
  SET    charge = 00 
  FROM   inserted i 
         INNER JOIN situations_final sfinal 
                 ON i.referencepiece = sfinal.referencepiece 
                    AND i.ancienposte = sfinal.ancienposte 
                    AND i.numerophase = sfinal.numerophase 
                    AND i.datestrategie = sfinal.datestrategie 
  WHERE sfinal.nouveauposte IS NULL;
```

Comment: Actually, I have a trigger that insert new rows depending on the data I insert manually. And in the rows inserted by the first trigger 'nouveauposte' is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are inserting more than one row in a single command, so the inserted table contains more than one row. As a consequence the sub query

```
SELECT sfinal.nouveauposte 
          FROM   situations_final sfinal 
                 INNER JOIN inserted i 
                         ON i.referencepiece = sfinal.referencepiece 
                            AND i.ancienposte = sfinal.ancienposte 
                            AND i.numerophase = sfinal.numerophase 
                            AND i.datestrategie = sfinal.datestrategie
```

contains more than one row too and cannot be compared to NULL that is a scalar value.

Comment: Yes. You are right ! 
My first trigger inserts more than one row. And obviously, I want to be able to give the value 0 to all the rows with nouveauposte = Null or somethin else. Is it impossible you think ?

Comment: I think the edited answer by Gordon Linoff is giving the solution :-)

Comment: I am going to try it. 
What about the other questions ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the other questions very well. A trigger can be recursive, what's the meaning of having only one trigger recursive? and I really don't understand the third

Comment: For the first question : I tried all the solutions you suggested and none of them works. The error message is the same.
For the second question: I mean I have many triggers, and I want to make one of them recursive (nested). 
The third one: 
To make a car you need 4 wheels;
for one wheel you need 2 specific components called 'XY'
So for your car, you need 2*4=8 XY.

Comment: It's more clear now but maybe I'm too tired and I don't understant what you need . What's the structure of the table. What data it contains? Can you give an example or resault based on certain data? Consider using SQL Fiddler to provide a working example, it can be very useful (http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: The table is called 'Nomenclatures' (Bill of materials in english) I have 3 elements:  The component mother, the component child and the quantity.
So basically it's three columns and the result I want to obtain should include more than 3 columns because for 'a mother', I need all its children in the same row !

Comment: mmmhhhh, not trivial at all! I'll think about it!

Comment: I didn't forget you, only I didn't have much time to think about it. I hope you still need the solution

Comment: Oh yes ! I still need it (the 3rd question)! Thank you so much

Comment: See my new answer, I made the query. Only the SQL Fiddle is not working, I don't know why (it worked this morning)

Comment: Did you see the answer?

Comment: Hello Paolo Costa,
Thank you very much for your efforts. I am so sorry, I was on a journey so that I couldn't check your answer. 
I've just tried it and it seems to be a problem :
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "QUANTITY" of recursive query "RESULT".

Comment: Can you put the comment under the other answer so we continue the discussion there?

Comment: Can you tak a look to my new post please ?

Answer (score 0):

I am ambitious :D I tried to improve the script:

```
WITH RESULT (MOTHER, CHILD, QUANTITY)
        as
        (
            select Mother, Child, CONVERT(Numeric(10,0), Quantity) as Quantity from bilangammestest 
            union all select M.mother, R.Child, CONVERT(Numeric(10,0), M.quantity * R.Quantity) as Quantity from Result R 
            INNER JOIN bilangammestest M ON M.Child = R.Mother

            )
            select * from result
            where mother not in (select child from bilangammestest )
```

Here are the data I have on my table "Bilangammestest":

Z   A   1

Z   Y   1

A   B   2

Y   B   2

B       C   3

Here are the result I get :

Z   A   1

Z   Y   1

Z   C   6

Z   C   6

Z   B   2

Z   B   2

Here is the Final result I want:

Z   A   1

Z   Y   1

Z   C   12

Z   B   4

I tried to do a 'sum' but I couldn't do it correctly :(

Comment: Maybe you should create a new question :-)  Each question should have a single isolated problem to be solved.